# From where the log file updated

Tags: linux

How to find, from where/which program using the log file and updating the entries/filling the log file in Linux.

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux: Would you please update the post and explain better what you want? Please try to not use one liners. If your command of English is weak, adding to the post will help others understand your needs and correct it.

Comment: Your question inspired me to write an article about that topic, so here it is https://mauro-stettler.blogspot.com/2016/01/monitoring-a-file-to-get-details-about-write-operations.html

Answer (score 1):

There is not simple answer to this, things you have available are these:

**Inotify**

You can use `inotify` to get notified whenever something changes a file. `inotify` itself is not a utility, it's an interface that's provided by the Linux kernel, but there are utilities like for example `inotifywait` from the `inotify-tools` package.

The problem with `inotify` is that it does not tell you which process has modified the file.

Example:

```
mst@mst-nb1:~$ inotifywait 123
Setting up watches.
Watches established.    # now i write to "123" in another terminal
123 MODIFY
```

**lsof**

One really great utility to figure out which process holds a file open is `lsof`. For example by doing `lsof /var/log/syslog` you can see which processes currently hold that file open.

The problem with `lsof` is that it cannot monitor that file over a time span, it can only give you a snapshot of the situation at the moment when you run it. In your case you want to know what's writing to that file, but you don't know for sure whether that file is permanently held open (most likely it's not). In case the writing process does not keep the file open all the time, then `lsof` won't help you much because it could only point you to the right process if you run it exactly at the moment when it's writing.

The reason why `lsof` can't monitor the file the same was as `inotify` does is because it gets it's information by simply scanning through the `/proc` filesystem, but it does not setup any watchers.

Example:

```
# Terminal 1 (I open the file)
mst@mst-nb1:~$ cat > 123

# Terminal 2
mst@mst-nb1:~$ lsof 123
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
cat     24097  mst    1w   REG  252,1        0 16791997 123
```

**loggedfs**

This might be your best chance, but it takes quite some effort to make it work. You can use fuse's `loggedfs` and mount it in the directory where your log file resides. Then it should give you detailed information about what's opening a file and when.

The only problem with `loggedfs` is that it is not as easy to use as some simple command line utility.

If you want to go through the hassle with `loggedfs` you can refer to the [documentation](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/)

**Conclusion**

The conclusion is that you have various possibilities, but there's no `simple` way.

Comment: Hello Mauro...The question is not clear at all, and you have had a lot of work. as the question is asked, and how you talk about monitoring /var/log/syslog...the obvious answer is syslog-ng, or rsyslog. No need to monitor for that. What you should be talking about is /dev/log. Btw I actually am not fond of fuse. Have a look at http://www.sysdig.org Cheers

Comment: You're right about that if he's using syslog. But according to the question this file could be written by literally anything. (I'm not fan of fuse either btw)

Comment: read better what I wrote. Programs talking to the syslog service use /dev/log, and syslog-ng, rsyslog or whatever is the one that writes by proxy to /var/log/syslog and family. I am just commenting on your post, it is not clear at all what the OP wants, and I wont waste my energy trying to guess.

Comment: true true, was an interesting exercise for myself anyway

Comment: (that what I am here for too)...cheers

Comment: Actually to be totally correct, programs write to /dev/log OR to port 514/UDP to send logs to the syslog daemon.  sysdig can monitor all of this.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro this is a really nice topic, so i wrote an article about it: http://mauro-stettler.blogspot.tw/2016/01/monitoring-a-file-to-get-details-about-write-operations.html

Answer (score 0):

Log files get their input from multiple sources. They are usually structured as lines, with the first word stating the source, timestamps, and some message.

There isn't a rigid format, each application (for example, Web server) has its own files, with their own formats (and often specific tools to summarize or otherwise mangle their contents).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way: auditd.

Example:

/etc/audit/audit.rules

```
-w /var/tmp/foo -p w -k foo
```

Here is an entry in /var/log/audit/audit.log:

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1454353834.695:29): 
arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=27cd460 a1=241 a2=1a4
a3=7fff4e278f30 items=2 ppid=10218 pid=10314 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0
suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts2 ses=3 comm="vi"
exe="/usr/bin/vim.basic" key="foo"
```

There is a good amount of information there including pid and executable. See also `aureport`.